# Is it possible to return redirect and return render together in django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, reload

I want to refresh the page after returning a render. I can use `return redirect` to the same page, but I am confused if I can use both return render and return redirect in the same view function. Is there any other way to reload the page other than redirect without affecting the return render? Or is there a way to re-run the `views.text_display()` function after each render?

About the project: I'm creating a typing practice program like [www.keybr.com](https://www.keybr.com)

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
import keyboard

def text_display(request):
    char_no = request.session.get('char_no', -1) + 1  
    request.session['char_no'] = char_no
    f = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\\text1.txt', "r+")
    file_contents = f.read()
    if char_no >= len(file_contents):
        return render(request,'type/main.html',{"key_press":"Test is over"})
    for line in file_contents:
        for ch in line:
            if keyboard.read_key() == file_contents[char_no]:
                ctx = {'text': file_contents, 'key_press':'You pressed the right key.'}
                f.close()
                return render(request, 'type/main.html', ctx)# Here after returning the render I want to re run this view function. So, reloading looks like a possible thing to do. 
            else:
                ctx = {'text': file_contents, 'key_press':'You pressed the wrong key.'}
                return render(request, 'type/main.html', ctx)# Here after returning the render I want to re run this view function. So, reloading looks like a possible thing to do.
```

Comment: Can you give an example view where you want to do this? Returning a redirect to the same page seems pointless when you can just return a normal response and the page content will update anyway?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have added the views.py file and described what I want. Feel free to ask for clarification. I'm new to Django so forgive me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah i am calling my view on every key press

Comment: after returning render why don't you use `window.location.reload();` , in a script tag in the document below ? What's the harm in that? you can even call using Set `timeout` if you want this refresh to happen lets after sometime

Comment: @AtifShafi Ig it works in Javascript. is there any way to do it in Python

Comment: I believe if you're calling your `view` on every keypress , i would advise either going for `long polling`, or `Django Channels` , now since its just a key press you should `ajax` , that may save you a lot of time ,

Comment: Uhh, you do know when a client accesses your website from the internet and not your server, that line `keyboard.read_key()` is _not_ going to work. You should look into using JavaScript instead.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ohk... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a redirect can be used in the same view function. Here is an example

```
def index(request):
  ctx = {}
  # one in 3 chance to redirect
  if random.randint(0, 2) > 1:
    return redirect ('/')

  return render(request, 'type/main.html', ctx)
```

Django redirect method returns a header[302] to the client, requesting a load to a new page. If you don't see the browswr refresh, it's because the browser didn't complete the request.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: I want to reload the page after running the return render. Basically, I want to run the view function again. So, is there any other way to re-run the view function?